# Searching for a string within a string in an attribute of an instance of a class

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I can't seam to get this db query in my rails app.  Here's my code from my controller:

```
User.where(:sport => "/\bFootball").all
```

That created this query/response:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."sport" = 'Football'
=> []
```

==========================================

But this:

```
User.where(:sport => "Football").all
```

Returns this:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."sport" = 'Football'
=>[ARRAY OF DESIRED USERS]
```

Not sure of the syntax here

Comment: `/\bFootball` means you search for the string "Football" but starting with a backspace. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: No - I want to search for "Football" regardless of what comes before or after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform a `LIKE` query in Rails you can do this:

```
User.where("users.sport LIKE ?", "%Football%").all
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a regular expression to make this query. The syntax for the same is:

```
User.where(sport: /Football/).to_a
```

Incase you want the term 'Football' to be case insensitive, you can use:

```
User.where(sport: /football/i).to_a
```

The reason for using the above syntax over:

`User.where("users.sport LIKE ?", "%Football%").all`

is that, like query will only work for SQL databases, while the regex based query suggested above will work for all SQL as well NoSQL database like mongodb.